# Homomorphic image of a projective module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory, projective-module

I just encountered one statement out of blue when reading section 20 of  'local representation theory '  by Alperin.

Every module is a homomorphic image of a projective module.

Not sure how to see this. Any hint would be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that every $R-$module $M$ is a quotient of a free $R-$module using the typical surjective map 
$$ \bigoplus_{x\in M} Rx\to M\to 0.$$
A free module is projective, so we are done.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your answer. I still don't quite follow. Would you please explain a bit the onto map? Thanks !

Comment: It's the map defined by sending $r\cdot x\mapsto rx\in M$ for each summand $Rx$ and using the universal property of the direct sum. Note that $\bigoplus_{x\in M} Rx$ consists of formal linear combinations of elements of $M$ with coefficients in $R$.